# How do I set up Weblogic 12c on Windows to start the http server on boot?

Tags: oracle, weblogic

Windows 2008 server, Weblogic 12c. I have a pretty simple setup using nodemanager. My problem is that our webhost likes to patch and reboot the server without telling us, and the HTTP server doesn't start up automatically after a reboot. Most Oracle documentation points me towards OPMN, but then I'm told that's no longer used in 12c.

Not sure where to start, any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved. We stopped then restarted the HTTP Server through the Weblogic Enterprise Manager, then copied the lastinvocation log into a new .cmd file. We added that .cmd file as a Windows service using NSSM, then set it to Automatic(Delayed Start) in Windows services.

Pretty ugly workaround, but it seems to work fine.

Answer (score 0):

Oracle says this isn't possible. If you have an Oracle support account you can look at Doc ID 1946552.1 and Bug 17694797, which state that it's not possible, Oracle has known about it since 2013, and are still reviewing whether or not they should do anything about it.

Answer (score 0):

Can you guide me where to find that lastinvocation log?

or can you share your command file?

Regards
Adeel

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://serverfault.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://serverfault.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://serverfault.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/540202)